# Этимология слова "ещё"

Tags: этимология

СвежО, горячО - на конце под ударением пишется О, но ещ**ё**. Почему в еще е- окончание. Может кто-то знает происхождение этого слова. В общем, главное понять, почему Ё в конце слова.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

Свежий - свежо, горячий - горячо, общий - общо, певучий - певуче  - во всех этих случаях после основы на шипящую при образовании наречия от прилагательного используется **суффикс О/Е** (в ударной и безударной позиции).

Но наречие "еще" **образовано не от прилагательного**, этимология его очень сложная и не сосем ясная, есть предположение, что слово образовано сложением частиц, при этом   нем происходили различные фонетические изменения. В любом случае **бука Ё на конце "ещё" входит  состав корня, к суффиксу О/Е отношения не имеет и поэтому может считаться исключением.**

Примечание. В словаре у  Черных отмечены следующие фонетические варианты (в  говорах): ощо, ошшо, оштё, ишо и др.

Comment: Большое, огромнейшее  вам спасибо.